# Python multiple solutions for function

Tags: python, function, solution

This code solves the "monkey coconut" problem, but how could I modify it to not only find the initial solution, but continue to find solutions?

(edit) Monkey coconut problem:
Five men and a monkey were shipwrecked on an island. They spent the first night gathering coconuts. During the night, one man woke up and decided to take his share of the coconuts. He divided them into five piles. One coconut was left over so he gave it to the monkey, then hid his share, put the rest back together, and went back to sleep.

Soon a second man woke up and did the same thing. After dividing the coconuts into five piles, one coconut was left over which he gave to the monkey. He then hid his share, put the rest back together, and went back to bed. The third, fourth, and fifth man followed exactly the same procedure. The next morning, after they all woke up, they divided the remaining coconuts into five equal shares. This time no coconuts were left over.

How many coconuts were there in the original pile?

```
def solve(sailors):
        nuts = sailors
        while True:
            n0, wakes = nuts, []
            for sailor in range(sailors + 1):
                portion, remainder = divmod(n0, sailors)
                wakes.append((n0, portion, remainder))
                if portion <= 0 or remainder != (1 if sailor != sailors else 0):
                    nuts += 1
                    break
                n0 = n0 - portion - remainder
            else:
                break
        return nuts, wakes
```

Comment: Why the `while True` that you always `break` after one iteration?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100%, but I *think* this does what you want.

First create a list of solutions, and add a new argument to your function 'limit'. This is used to set an upper limit to exit out of the recursion.

Once you've got a solution, append it to the solutions list.

Now check if your nuts variable has exceeded your upper limit. If it hasn't then recur the function, but starting from your current nuts variable so that it doesn't get found again.

I'm not 100% on the monkey coconut problem, but this gives me the nuts values of `[11, 23, 47, 95, 191]` for a sailors value of 5.

If this isn't right, then you would want to play around with passing the original sailors value and check if it's in the solutions list, if not continue the loop.

```
solutions = []
def solve(sailors, limit):
        nuts = sailors
        while True:
            n0, wakes = nuts, []
            for sailor in range(sailors + 1):
                portion, remainder = divmod(n0, sailors)
                wakes.append((n0, portion, remainder))
                if portion <= 0 or remainder != (1 if sailor != sailors else 0):
                    nuts += 1
                n0 = n0 - portion - remainder
            else:
                break
        solutions.append((nuts, wakes))
        
        if nuts < limit:
            return solve(nuts, limit)
        else:
            return solutions

print(solve(5, 100))
```

EDIT:

OK I think the solution above is wrong, but can't be sure as I don't fully understand the problem.

Now I'm setting a default keyword arg of nuts to None. Checking if it's None, if so setting it to sailors. Then passing it on the recursion. This keeps the sailors value the same but increments the nuts each time

```
solutions = []
def solve(sailors, limit, nuts=None):
        if not nuts:
            nuts = sailors
        while True:
            n0, wakes = nuts, []
            for sailor in range(sailors + 1):
                portion, remainder = divmod(n0, sailors)
                wakes.append((n0, portion, remainder))
                if portion <= 0 or remainder != (1 if sailor != sailors else 0):
                    nuts += 1
                n0 = n0 - portion - remainder
            else:
                break
        solutions.append((nuts))
        
        if nuts < limit:
            return solve(sailors, limit, nuts=nuts)
        else:
            return solutions

print(solve(5, 100))
```

This gives the following result:

```
[11, 16, 21, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 49, 53, 58, 63, 68, 74, 79, 83, 87, 93, 98, 102]
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.

Comment: No problem, if it doesn't work and there is somewhere that documents what the expected solutions to the problem would be for certain values, this is the kind of thing I would set up a test script on and do TDD. Either way, I think the solution definitely lies in recursion.

Comment: When I do "print(solve(5,10))", it prints out (5, 1, 0), followed by (0, 0, 0) however many times specified. Do you know why? Also, I am only trying to find solutions for coconuts in the original pile. The code I have is probably a little unnecessary, but the math itself is confusing.

Comment: I'm genuinely not sure tbh as like you say the math is a bit confusing and I don't fully understand what's going on, I'm just looking at it from a programming point of view. The (0,0,0) was what I was getting for your wakes values. I have edited my answer as I think my original solution is wrong.

Comment: If you only need the nuts values, then don't add the wakes to the solutions as I have in the second solution.

Comment: I think I did the math wrong, as the lowest possible solution, given that there are 5 sailors, should be 15621. I will try to rewrite the function. but it is confusing.

Comment: I was just thinking that when looking at the problem in a bit more depth